# How to iterate over a list to remove index of item?

Tags: python, list, loops

I have 2 lists:

```
l1=[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
l2 = [0,2]
```

L2 contains a list of indexes. I want to delete the index of the element in l1 that correspond to the index in l2.

How can that be done?

```
for i in l2:
    l2.pop(i)
```

Doesn't work because the index changes after popping the first one.

I saw this answer somewhere but its not working by deleteing indexes:

```
somelist = [x for x in somelist if not determine(x)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l2 = set(l2)   # for speedy lookups
l1 = [x for i, x in enumerate(l1) if i not in l2]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can always sort the list of indices first and then iterate through them in reverse so you can ensure the right values are deleted

```
for i in sorted(l2)[::-1]: l1.pop(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go in reverse order to avoid that problem:

```
l1 = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
l2 = [0, 2]

for i in reversed(l2):
    del l1[i]
print l1 # [(3, 4)]
```